# Javascript call to ASP.NET Page Method working on IE but not on Chrome / Firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome, pagemethods

I have the following code in an ASPX page that, when a PayPal icon is clicked, connects with a Page Method and retrieves the PayPal token of a session. When this is executed in IE, it works perfectly, but when it is executed in Chrome or Firefox, the $.ajax call of jQuery returns immediately an error of code 0.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("input.PayPal").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "MyCurrentPage.aspx/PayPal",
                    data: "{IdRecibo : " + $(this).attr("data-value") + "}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.d.Result == "Success") {
                            window.location.href = result.d.Redirect;
                        }
                        else
                            alert("El servicio de PayPal está temporalmente deshabilitado.");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the unusual url format `ListadoExpedienteEconomico.aspx/PayPal`.  I notice Chrome/FF somtimes parses folder paths differently from IE.

Comment: I've tried to check the requests and return values with Fiddler (since after all, a Page Method call is a Service call) and return values are as expected.

Comment: Is there any error description on thrownError?

Comment: No error description. Only code 0.

Comment: check the console in chrome, should be an error.
other thing you can do is put a breakpoint on the script to debug, or add a "debugger;" both "success" as in "error"

Comment: I've tried the url format, as @mellamokb suggested, to no use.

`url: '<%= Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "/PayPal" %>',`

The method call is still bein called properly, since Fiddler catches the call being made and the results being transmitted by the server. But Chrome still does not work. IExplorer works perfectly.

Comment: Amazing!
@MCSI, I tried what you say and when trying a step-by-step trace on the javascript function it actually does work!
What might cause this? If I execute it without debugging it still does not work.

Comment: Great @IsaacLlopis!! but what result you get? success or error? maybe the problem is in other part of the code...

Comment: The result is as expected... but only when I am in debugging mode and stop the process just before the success call. If I do it inside the success or error calls, it always ends in error.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea on what might be happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight change of code solves the problem with Chrome. It looks like the JSON response of the ASP.NET Page Method is not correctly parsed if `return false;` is not the last part of the `$.ajax` call.

This is the working code:

```
    $("input.PayPal").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "/PayPal" %>',
            data: JSON.stringify({ IdRecibo: $(this).attr("data-value") }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: "false",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.d.Result == "Success") {
                    window.location.href = result.d.Redirect;
                }
                else
                    alert("El servicio de PayPal está temporalmente deshabilitado.");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON does not look to be well formed. Try

```
"{ 'IdRecibo': 'value'}"
```

Comment: As I say, it does work in Internet Explorer perfectly. And the Page Method call is made both in Chrome and Explorer. Data is sent properly, therefore.

Comment: Depends on which serialiser each browser is using... so this answer is not really wrong - and may even be right ;-)

Comment: But the results thrown by fiddler are the same in Chrome and Explorer, so the Page Method must have been called properly, isn't it?